# How to stream data to browser without caching from spring

Tags: java, spring, servlet-3.0

I have written the below code using Spring to print the data to the browser as when its executes

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void get(HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        res.setHeader("CacheControl", "no-cache");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            res.getWriter().write(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
```

but server sends the results once the loop is been completed but I would like to display each line to the browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. you will have to  generate five requests from front end with interval of 1000ms and will have to remove this for loop from backend code.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood Processing time can't be predicted so I would like to stream the server console to the browser

Comment: According to my knowledge I don't think its possible. HTTP don't work in this way. You will be required to fetch it continuously from front end.

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve this functionality you have have to look into *web sockets*. Its a TCP-based protocol.